PhpStorm all text keywords completion
While working in Sublime Text, any text key, regardless of where, how, or in what type it is used, is automatically suggested for completion.
However, PhpStorm does not behave this way. It only provides completion and suggestions where it is contextually appropriate for the parameter structure.
Consider the following function:
$this->auth->checkRole('LOGIN');

In this example, Sublime Text would suggest LOGIN if you type L elsewhere, but PhpStorm does not behave the same way.
Sublime Text recognizes all text keys in PHP and suggests them universally. PhpStorm, however, does not provide this kind of universal suggestion.
How can I enable this behavior in PhpStorm?
You can watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k60T-lGrR2g&feature=youtu.be
I want it to find and remind these words in the PhpStorm like Sublime Text does.

I don't think there's an option for this. However, the AI assistant in recent versions may be able to guess that LOGIN is a possible completion.

But wouldn't this question be better sent to JetBrains tech support? If you're not paying for tech support, you could ask in their community forum.

Only 1 option as far as I'm concerned (my knowledge) -- Hippie Completion. It's a bit different from standard code completion, not super easy to use. Anyway -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion
